# element could not be found selenium webdriver mobile

Tags: ios, ruby, selenium, mobile, appium

I keep getting the below error message.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: An element could not be 
located on the page using the given search parameters.
from /Users/shafiq.malik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-
3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
```

I am currently in the process of setting up a ruby/appium framework for mobile testing using selenium.

Here is my env.rb file.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'pry'

#APP_PATH = 'PlainNote.app'

def capabilities123
  {
      'automationName' => 'XCUITest',
      'platformName' => 'iOS',
      'deviceName' =>  'iPhone Simulator',
      'platform' => 'Mac',
      'version' => '9.2',
      'app' => '/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-class-
booking-mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app'}
end

def server_url
   'http://localhost:8000/wd/hub'
end

def seleniumabc
   @driver ||= Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => 
capabilities123, :url => server_url)
end

After { @driver.quit }
```

Can somebody please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are aware but XCUITest automation is only supported from xcode 8 and iOS 9.3+ .

So please change following things:
Update your XCode to 8+ latest version.
Update your appium_lib gem version to latest version .
Update your appium version to 1.6.4 .
Change capability iOS version to 9.3 or 10.3
Change Capability to specific mobile version and not iPhone Simulator .

Here are sample capabilities:

```
caps = {
      :platformName => "iOS",
      :deviceName => "iPhone 6",
      :platformVersion => "9.3",
      :app => app_path,
      :noReset => 'true',
      :newCommandTimeout => "30",
      :automationName => "XCUITest",
      :sendKeyStrategy => 'setValue'
  }
```

Try these and let me know.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I have managed to find a solution to this issue. Thanks for your help anyways much appreciated.

Comment: would you like to share your solution here please as an answer?

Comment: Appium has XCUITest working on top of appium and creates an instance of the mobile app everytime you run a test. So it converts your tags like class, name, id etc etc to XCUIElementTypeclass, XCUIElementTypename, XCUIElementTypeid etc. This its only accepts the following: `[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id`. Thus is used @driver.find_element(:name, "APACHE CORDOVA") and it worked. I hope this helps!!! I am going to try and look into this further so I can have a better understanding/